# Java desktop jar to android

Tags: java, android, jar

I have desktop simulation which is developed in java (jar file). Is there a way to convert java desktop application to an Android app.

Comment: Yes, the right way would be to learn Android programming and rewrite your app. ;)

Comment: Android does understand Java (6) but not how to draw windows for example. If your application has a clean separation of model and view you could probably use the model part as is but you'll have to write a different View part for Android. There are no tools that can do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to convert a java desktop app to an Android app, you would have to get hold of the source code and adjust to make it run on the Android platform, make it work with the Android lifecycle and make it respond to the input methods provided.